# Read-Write image from a URL

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to download an `image` from an url...My code is :

```
String url = "http://mysite.com/image.xyz"
```

where `xyz` can be jpg/png/jpeg..

now am able read the image from url using

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Now what i need is that while writing the image to a file using:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "variable" , new File("C:\\out1.jpg"));
```

i need the value of `variable` to be replaced by the value of `xyz`...where value of xyz will be `extracted` from url....

So how to achieve this........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class java.net.URL :

```
URL u = new URL(url);
String name = u.getFile();
String ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

In ext you have the extension.

[EDIT]

A few notes on other answers posted :

They are both good answers unless you happen to have an URL with query params (like http://www.example.org/folder/file.png?size=big ).

Using last three chars, it would return "big" instead of png.

Also, if the image is .jpeg it would return "peg".

Using simply after last "." in string is as well dangerous, more or less for the same reason of query params: it would return ".png?size=big".

java.net.URL will take into account all these situations, and return the file name only. For there, extracting the extension is still a matter of "finding the point", but at least on an already cleaned String.

Comment: In the question the variable `url` is of type `String`.

Comment: @Kees yes, URL u = new URL(url) will initialize a URL named "u" using the string named "url" ... sorry for the naming, i understad it is confusing, but since "url" was already used I tried to adapt myself.

Comment: *"java.net.URL will take into account all these situations, and return the file name only."*  Not using the `getFile()` method it won't.  The `String` returned by that method includes the name as well as the query parameters and values.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just take the substring after the last dot?

Alternatively use Apache Commons FileIO's class `FilenameUtils` which provides a method to get the extension from a path.

Please note that you also might want to add that extension to your output file, it might get confusing if `out.jpg` was actually a PNG file.